# Translating ocean data to a raster format and displaying with MapServer

Tags: postgis, raster, openlayers, mapserver

I am having extreme difficulty correctly displaying a raster layer that originates from a netCDF file Source: (https://oceandata.sci.gsfc.nasa.gov/MODIS-Aqua/L3SMI/2017/001/)

I can use gdal_translate to make a GeoTTIFF out of the dataset and even further raster2pgsql to create a table for PostGIS. Regardless of the format I can't correctly output the raster file from just my mapfile. What it does show appears to be just a few pixels from a corner. I'm hoping it's as simple as misunderstanding what extent or size to use, which I have set at -180 -90 180 90

UPDATE: Ran gdalinfo on the tif file instead of the netCDF to get the translated extent. Now just to figure out how to display it properly in openlayers..

```
Files: v2017chl_1.tif
Size is 8640, 4320
Coordinate System is `'
Image Structure Metadata:
INTERLEAVE=BAND
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (    0.0,    0.0)
Lower Left  (    0.0, 4320.0)
Upper Right ( 8640.0,    0.0)
Lower Right ( 8640.0, 4320.0)
Center      ( 4320.0, 2160.0)
Band 1 Block=8640x1 Type=Float32, ColorInterp=Gray
```

Comment: What does `gdalinfo /path/to/yournetcdf.nc` show?

Comment: Make sure you are using the subdataset name, not just the path to the .nc file. i.e `gdal_translate NETCDF:"A2017001.L3m_DAY_IOP_adg_443_giop_9km.nc":adg_443_giop out.tif`. You can get the subdataset names from `gdalinfo yournetcdf.nc`

Comment: What do you use as projection in your mapfile?